# InfluxDB v2.0 running in docker - ERR: received status code 401 from server

Tags: docker, influxdb, influxdb-2

I'm trying to run some experiments with InfluxDB in my local machine but for some reason, `auth` is not working (or I'm not being able to make it work).

I create a docker network running:

```bash
docker network create --driver bridge influxdb-telegraf-net
```

Later, I simply bind the `8086` of the container to the localhost's, attach a volume for the data files, and that's pretty much all:

```bash
docker run -d --name=influxdb -p 8086:8086 -v /tmp/influx:/root/.influxdb2 --net=influxdb-telegraf-net influxdb:2.0
```

Then, I run the following command to set up InfluxDB inside of the container:

```bash
docker exec -it influxdb influx setup
```

And I fill the username, password, organization... and so on.

However, when I'm "done" with the set up, I use my local influx client to create a new database, but every command I run returns: `ERR: received status code 401 from server`.

For instance:

```bash
myuser@mymachine:~$ influx
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 2.0.9
InfluxDB shell version: 1.6.7~rc0
> show databases
ERR: received status code 401 from server
```

I'm not sure where the issue comes from. I tried running `auth` but after filling the username and password, it still returns the same error.

I'm sure it has to be some small - yet simple - detail, because I'm not doing anything fancy.

TIA!

### EDIT

When running `docker inspect influxdb-telegraf-net`:

```bash
myuser@mymachine:~$ docker inspect influxdb-telegraf-net 
[
    {
        "Name": "influxdb-telegraf-net",
        "Id": "33afd698984c851c86e36e083522acfac5310a87313691c047826adb073a6065",
        "Created": "2022-06-25T10:15:06.630948524+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "e1ddbd36321b798a9343b3061d73ab438d012859134f73b7d072027729694917": {
                "Name": "influxdb",
                "EndpointID": "08e5698c04ea2532de6880946ed90c7c80e274b8920f4ce560b7c63f4a4f0f7a",
                "MacAddress": "00:00:aa:00:00:00",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

**Note** that I changed my `MacAddress` to a dummy add just in case.

Comment: Show us docker inspect network yournetwork.

Comment: Network is not an issue,double check volume mounts.

Comment: @RichardRublev I think the issue has to do with InfluxDB auth itself, rather than the fact that is set-up using docker. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after checking the versions (first thing I should have done!) I found out:

```bash
myuser@mymachine:~$ /usr/bin/influx --version
InfluxDB shell version: 1.6.7~rc0
```

and

```bash
myuser@mymachine:~$ docker exec -it influxdb /bin/bash
root@e1ddbd36321b:/# influx version
Influx CLI 2.0.9 (git: d1233b7951) build_date: 2021-10-01T21:09:53Z
```

So yeah, that's basically the issue. The versions of the client and the DB must match.

Keep in mind that InfluxDB 2.0 or greater does not have the out-of-the-box CLI that lets you enter the DB cli. You need to compile it by yourself as per [issue #19986](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/19986).